# Why is FMX's DrawLine() function not working properly?

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder

I'm using C++Builder 11 Community Edition on a Windows 10 PC.

I'm trying to draw lines. When I make a VCL app, it all works fine, but I want to use FMX to take advantage of the GPU.

The FMX code is giving me blurred lines with `Stroke->Thickness` set to `1.0`. I need the line thickness to be 1 pixel wide. This will eventually be a program that draws a bar graph.

This is the VCL code:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Canvas->Pen->Width = 1;
    Canvas->Pen->Color = (Graphics::TColor) clBlack;

    Canvas->MoveTo(100,100);
    Canvas->LineTo(500,100);
    Canvas->MoveTo(100,101);
    Canvas->LineTo(300,101);
    Canvas->MoveTo(100,102);
    Canvas->LineTo(500,102);
}
```

[image: VCL lines with windows magnifier]

This is the FMX code:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Canvas->BeginScene();
//  Canvas->Clear(TAlphaColorRec::Blue);

    Canvas->Stroke->Color = TAlphaColorRec::Black;
    Canvas->Stroke->Thickness = 1.0;
    Canvas->DrawLine(TPointF(100,100), TPointF(500,100), 1.0);
    Canvas->DrawLine(TPointF(100,101), TPointF(300,101), 1.0);
    Canvas->DrawLine(TPointF(100,102), TPointF(500,102), 1.0);

    Canvas->EndScene();
}
```

[image: FMX lines with windows magnifier]

I've tried different opacities and line thicknesses. If I repeat the line draw function 10 times, it looks better, but this is obviously not the way to go!

Can anybody help with this?

Comment: Just a thought - is your FMX app setup to be DPI-aware? If not, then Windows will have to scale your UI when rendering it on High-DPI monitors, and that can cause the UI to appear blurry. I don't know if FMX has any built-in support for High-DPI handling, but Embarcadero has been working hard on High-DPI support in the VCL for several releases now.

Comment: This is because of antialiased graphics in FMX. An integer coordinate is on a pixel boundary. It will therefore draw the line spanning 2 pixels with half the colour on each. The solution is just to offset all your coordinates by 0.5 pixels.

Comment: I had set the DPI Awareness in the Manifest to Per Monitor V2. I've tried all the other settings in there to no avail. I forgot to mention I'm running on a 1920x1080 monitor as this app will end up on such a machine. I had compiled the program on an older low-dpi version of C++ Builder (XE7) with the same results. For now, I will stick with the VCL version and investigate the FMX issue some more when I have time.

Comment: Solved it. Set Form Quality property to High Performance.

Comment: Setting to High Performance solves it because anti-aliasing is turned off. This may reduce quality of other graphics though. The best option is to offset your coordinates by 0.5 pixels. That will solve the problem without reducing image quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to offset all coordinates by half a pixel so that it's drawing from the center of the pixel rather than at a pixel boundary. This ensures that the anti-aliased graphics doesn't blend the pixels over a boundary. You could also set the Form's Quality property to HighPerformance to disable anti-aliasing, but that may negatively affect graphics quality on other parts of the form where you may want to keep anti-aliasing.

The following works with Quality set to HighQuality

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Canvas->BeginScene();
//  Canvas->Clear(TAlphaColorRec::Blue);

    Canvas->Stroke->Color = TAlphaColorRec::Black;
    Canvas->Stroke->Thickness = 1.0;
    Canvas->DrawLine(TPointF(100.5,100.5), TPointF(500.5,100.5), 1.0);
    Canvas->DrawLine(TPointF(100.5,101.5), TPointF(300.5,101.5), 1.0);
    Canvas->DrawLine(TPointF(100.5,102.5), TPointF(500.5,102.5), 1.0);

    Canvas->EndScene();
}
```

Comment: Thanks XylemFlow. I did try your suggestion. It didn't work originally as I only offset the Y values and not the X values. It's working great now.